# Heyting algebras and infinite distributive law

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory

I want to prove that "a complete lattice satisfies the infinite distributive law $a\wedge(\vee{S})=\vee\{a\wedge s|s\in S\}$ iff it is a Heyting algebra".

I proved "if" part but can't "only if" part.

I defined $a\rightarrow b$ as $(\vee \{s|a\wedge s=0\})\vee b$ and tried to prove $a\rightarrow a=1$ but failed.

Comment: Do you rather mean $\vee\{s\ |\ a\wedge s\leq b\}$?

Comment: I edited. I wanted to write $(\vee \{s|a\wedge s=0\})\vee b$.

Comment: Remember that $a\to b \Leftrightarrow (\neg a)\vee b$ only in classical logic, but Heyting algebras model intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Can you write an answer then for your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of having an answer available to someone who arrives to this page, I have written the following answer.

Recall that a bounded lattice $L$ is a Heyting algebra when for each $a$ and $b$ in $L$ there exists an element $a \to b$ with the property that for each $w$ in $L$, $w \leq a\to b \Leftrightarrow a \wedge w \leq b$.

Now suppose that $L$ is a complete lattice satisfying the infinite distributivity law. Let us check that the correct definition of implication is $a \to b = \vee \{s\,|\,a\wedge s \leq b\}$. If $w \leq a \to b$, then $a \wedge w \leq a \wedge (\vee \{s\,|\,a\wedge s \leq b\}) = \vee\{a\wedge s\,|\,a\wedge s \leq b\}\leq b$. Conversely, if $a \wedge w \leq b$, then trivially $w \leq a \to b$ (since $w \in \{s\,|\,a\wedge s \leq b\}$).

The fact that every complete lattice $L$ which is a Heyting algebra satisfies the infinite distributive law follows from the fact that for each $a$ in $L$, the maps defined by $s \mapsto a\wedge s$ and $s \mapsto (a \to s)$ are the left and right adjoins of a Galois connection.

Let us recall why this is so. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are partially orderded sets, and that $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are monotone (i.e. order preserving) maps, we say that $f$ and $g$ are part of a Galois connection when $f(x) \leq y \Leftrightarrow x \leq g(y)$. When this is the case $f$ is called the left (or lower) adjoint (of $g$) and $g$ is called the right (or upper) adjoint (of $f$). It is easy to see that the infinite distributivity law above corresponds to the fact that the left adjoints $s\mapsto a\wedge s$ preserve joins. Let us prove that left adjoints always preserve joins. Suppose that the join of $S \subseteq X$ exists in $X$ and suppose for some $w\in Y$ that for each $s \in S$, $f(s)\leq w$. Using the Galois connection we have for each $s \in S$,  $s \leq g(w)$ and hence $\vee S \leq g(w)$. Using the Galois connection again we have that $f(\vee S) \leq w$ proving that $f(\vee S)=\vee\{ f(s)\,|\,s\in S\}$.

Let us end by making several remarks:

- The first part of this answer can also be phrased as part of a more general theory. Suppose that $f: X\to Y$ is a monotone map between partially ordered sets. If $f$ preserves arbitary joins (i.e. whichever ones exist) and for each $y$ in $Y$, the join of $\{x\,|\,x \in X, f(x) \leq y\}$ exists, then $f$ is the left adjoint of a Galois connection with right adjoint $g$ defined by $g(y) = \vee\{x\,|\,x \in X, f(x) \leq y\}$.
- Everything can be generalizer further by replacing partial orders and monotone maps by categories and functors.